# Добавление изображений в товар

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

хочу сделать слайдер на странице товара. Как мне добавить поле в админке wordpress в которое я бы смог добавлять неограниченное количество изображений без плагинов.

Answer (score 0):

В woocommerce есть функционал для изображения товара и для галереи по умолчанию

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/adding-product-images-and-galleries/

Фрагмент кода для работы с галереей

```
<?php
    global $product;

    $attachment_ids = $product->get_gallery_image_ids();

    foreach( $attachment_ids as $attachment_id ) {
        echo $image_link = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id );
    }
?>
```